# как в git bash проложить путь к папке которая лежит на рабочем столе?

Tags: git

Какую команду нужно ввести в git bash чтобы проложить путь к папке на рабочем столе? cd ~/Desktop ведёт на папку Desktop, а не на рабочий стол.

Comment: "Рабочий стол" - это виртуальный объект, собираемый из содержимого папки `Desktop` профиля пользователя, папки `Desktop` профиля специального пользователя Public (ранее называлась "Все пользователи"), и некоторых виртуальных объектов типа корзины.

Comment: Для начала следует выяснить путь к этой папке. Откройте ее в проводнике и "Cкопировать путь" - тогда путь окажется в буфере обмена

Comment: @ГерманБорисов В своем предыдущем комментарии я не предлагал копировать адрес рабочего стола из строки адреса... Я предлагал найти папку (которая на Рабочем столе) в Проводнике, выделить ее и использовать команду "Cкопировать путь" не лазия ни в какие контекстные меню.

Comment: @user7860670, вы правы. Для конкретного объекта внутри рабочего стола отображается полный реальный адрес.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо, ваш способ оказался рабочим)